# jquery dropdown-menu fadeIn("slow") is not working

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu").click(
        function() { $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeIn("slow");
        },
        function() { $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop().fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

jquery dropdown fadeIn slow is not getting applied on click what would be the problem

Comment: Any console errors? Please elaborate *not working*. Also if possible post a snippet or jsfiddle.

Comment: `click()` (https://api.jquery.com/click/) does not have 2 parameters that can both be a function - first is event data, second is event handler, thus this code would not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass two functions to click handler, instead call another function after finishing first one. Also you are using `$('.dropdown-menu', this)` which means you are trying to find `'.dropdown-menu'` from within clicked `'.dropdown-menu'` which is wrong. use `$(this)` only. see below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu").click(function() { 
       $(this).fadeIn("slow", function(){
          $(this).fadeOut("slow");
       });
    });
});
```